# Combine / merge current element with previous element of list

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
   lst=['*PF4', 'PF6', '#', 'PF2', '\PWD(5D)','PWD(30)']
                ['*PF4#', 'PF2', '\PWD(89)','PWD(31)']
                 ['*PF4', 'PF6', '#', 'PF2', '\PWD(89)','PWD(31)']
```

Here is my code which I tried:

```
             for i in lst:
                    if i.startswith("*") and i.endswith("#"): 
                        new_lst.append(i)
                    elif i.startswith("*"): 
                        new_lst.append(i)
                    elif i.endswith("#"): 
                        new_lst.append(i)
```

The code checks if element starts or ends with `*` or `#` and if so appends the single element into another list.

I am parsing through the list and trying to capture the elements between `*` and `#`.

What I am currently getting is:

```
            ['*PF4', 'PF6', '#']
            ['*PF4#']
            ['*PF4', 'PF6', '#']
```

What I want is:

```
            ['*PF4', 'PF6#']
            ['*PF4#']
            ['*PF4', 'PF6#']
```

Comment: What's with the downvotes? The OP has a clear problem statement, an (almost) MCVE, typical input, and expected output.

Comment: This is a little tricky, since the `#` can be in the following string. Can `*` also be in the preceding string?

Comment: BTW, it looks like your `lst` is supposed to be a list of lists, but it's missing the outer brackets & a few commas. You should fix that.

Comment: PM 2Ring Thank you so much for your concern, really appreciate it. For your question: * wont be in preceding string.

Comment: My lst looks the same as it is displayed here because I am passing the lst as parameter from other function.

Comment: Ok, but in its current state your `lst` is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: PM 2Ring Thanks. I will check with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach. Using a check flag. `checkFlag`

**Ex:**

```
lst=[['*PF4', 'PF6', '#', 'PF2', '\PWD(5D)','PWD(30)'],
     ['*PF4#', 'PF2', '\PWD(89)','PWD(31)'],
     ['*PF4', 'PF6', '#', 'PF2', '\PWD(89)','PWD(31)']]


def getValue(lst):
    checkFlag = False
    res = []
    for i in lst:
        if checkFlag:
            if i.endswith("#"):
                res[-1] = res[-1]+i
                checkFlag = False
            else:
                res.append(i)

        if i.startswith("*") and i.endswith("#"): 
            res.append(i)
        elif i.startswith("*"):
            res.append(i)
            checkFlag = True
    return res


print(getValue(lst[0]))
print(getValue(lst[1]))
print(getValue(lst[2]))
```

**Output:**

```
['*PF4', 'PF6#']
['*PF4#']
['*PF4', 'PF6#']
```

Comment: Rakesh Thanks for your answer but its not a list of lists. Its individual list generated without comma separator. And my expected output is: 
           ['*PF4', 'PF6#']
           ['*PF4#']
           ['*PF4', 'PF6#']

Comment: @PythonBang Yes i understood. I just used it as an example to demo the solution & logic.

Comment: Rakesh I have used the flag logic itself, Just that dint mention it here. But I am unable to achieve my target output

Comment: Updated snippet for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way of doing it using enumerate and joining the next elem of the list if he is equal to '#' to the current one

```
lst1 = ['*PF4', 'PF6', '#', 'PF2', '\PWD(5D)','PWD(30)']
lst2 = ['*PF4#', 'PF2', '\PWD(89)','PWD(31)']
lst3 = ['*PF4', 'PF6', '#', 'PF2', '\PWD(89)','PWD(31)']

def lst_pars(lst):
    new_lst = []

    for e, i in enumerate(lst):
        if i == '#':
            continue
        if e + 1 < len(lst) and lst[e + 1] == '#':
            i = i + lst[e + 1]
        if (i.startswith("*") and i.endswith("#")) or i.startswith("*") or i.endswith("#"):
            new_lst.append(i)
    return new_lst

new_lst1 = lst_pars(lst1)
new_lst2 = lst_pars(lst2)
new_lst3 = lst_pars(lst3)
```

output:

```
['*PF4', 'PF6#']
['*PF4#']
['*PF4', 'PF6#']
```

Comment: bboumend Its not a single list

Comment: I have updated the code to use a function just call the func on each list to get the new list then do what you want with it